# MonoTouch for iOS Microphone FLAC File

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, speech, flac

I'm programming an App for `iOS` which should recognise the human user speech with `MonoTouch`.
I need to use the microphone and convert the Voice-File into `FLAC` format, in order to send it to the `Google Speech API`.

Comment: You have not actually asked a question.  You've just told us what you want.  Is there a specific part of this that is causing a problem?  Or is there some code you're having trouble with?

Comment: i'm sorry, my question is if this is possible and how to convert the microphone output (a .caf file i think) into a flac format file?