# MonoTouch iOS FLAC File Speech Recognition

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, speech-recognition, flac

I'm programming an App for iOS which should recognise the human user speech with MonoTouch. I need to use the microphone and convert the Voice-File into `FLAC` format, in order to send it to the Google Speech API.
Are there any Libraries/Code examples, or is it possible to build a `Speech-Recognition` App for `iOS` using `MonoTouch` and for example the `Google Speech API`?
Or is it possible to convert the audio Output(a .caf file) to a .flac file?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119758/monotouch-for-ios-microphone-flac-file)